# Convert Date from Excel Import

Tags: sql, excel, date, ssis

I am working on automating some data that I receive from Germany. The Date format comes in as DD.MM.YYYY and I need it to be MM/DD/YYYY.

I am building an import package using SSIS and I added a derived column to change the date format.

I first tried to use

```
(DT_DATE) [CalendarDay]
```

but I keep getting an error at the Derived Column when I execute the package.

```
[Derived Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.
The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error 
row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Date]" 
specifies failure on error.
```

So I moved through the many examples in StackExchange (all that I could find at least) and was met with the same error or not the desired output.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Import the data into a staging table as varchar.  Then update a date column in the same table from that varchar field.

Comment: I agree with Dan. you can use CONVERT(date, '12.3.2013',104)

Comment: I created a derived column to convert the Date (DT_WSTR, 10)CalendarDay (new Column = DateConv)then added another Derived Column to convert it to a proper date (DT_DATE)DateConv. I received the same error in the second Derived Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Source :- Flat file use DT_date for Date column
2) Derived Column :- Replace this with using

SUBSTRING([Column 2],4,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([Column 2],5,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING([Column 2],7,2)

and use DT_DATE IN Datatype

3) Destination :- Use datetime as datatype for date

Run it

Thanks!

Comment: here derived column is CalendarDay replace it with substrings mentioned.

Comment: I can not use the Flat File source as this is an Excel Document that is updated Daily by an SAP job. I am unable to change the format of the cells because the formatting would be replaced by the SAP extraction daily.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

--   Issue with date column... use DT_Date and then in derived column use substring to include

```
 // so date will become 2009/02/05 and then transfer data to destination...
```

it will work out..

Thanks!

Nilesh

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand what you are explaining. Can you provide a little more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by using the Substring Method that was provided by user3112708 and making an minor alteration to the numbering sequence.

```
SUBSTRING(CalendarDay,4,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING(CalendarDay,1,2) + "/" + 
SUBSTRING(CalendarDay,7,4)
```

Thank you every one for your help.